# How to insert default values to a table with not null columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have several tables with different number of columns, each can be either `real` or `int`, both `not null` (I can define them all real if required).

I would like to write a query that inserts a row with all zeros.

`INSERT [TablesName] DEFAULT VALUES` works good for nullable columns.

I can't use `INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) VALUES (0, 0.0);` as I don't know the number of columns.

Is there a query that would insert a new row with default values for not null tables?

Comment: How can you *not* know the number of columns of a table? Btw: the nullable attribute is independent of the default value of a column.

Comment: use sp_help, or join sys.tables to sys.columns, or use the GUI, but determine the structure of the table before you write an insert.

Comment: I am writing a `C#` function that accepts a table name, truncates it and then initializing it with a single row - the row should contain all zeros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put defaults on the columns, so that your `DEFAULT VALUES` works.

In your table definitions just put `DEFAULT 0` after each column definition - should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server there is also a bit more flexibility.
You can specify that a specific column use it's default value in the VALUES clause, like this:

```
create table #t(x varchar(1) not null default 'x',y varchar(1) not null default 'y');

insert into #t(x,y) values(default,default);

select * from #t;
drop table #t;
go
```